# What are these white pellet in my speaker used for?

Tags: acoustics, electronics, electrical-engineering

These are the pics of the speakers in my surface laptop.

What are these white pellets used for.

[image]
[image]

Similar pellets can be found in many tiny speakers of iPhones and Samsung phones.

Comment: I see dust, not pellets

Comment: second image white pellets in a black circular container is the one i am referring to.

Comment: I suggest you edit that pic to point to that specific place and post that to the engineering stack overflow